# MPAndroidChart: How to customise bar value labels

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart in my Android app. I use a `BarChart` composed of `BarEntry`. I also enabled the y-values to be displayed on top of the bar.

My issue is that I want the values on top of the bars to be whole numbers like `5`. But currently the values display as `5.00`.

[image: the top of a single bar from a bar chart with the value label above it displaying "5.00"]

So how do I make `5.00` display as `5`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Values are formatted using the `IValueFormatter` interface. Here's a simple formatter that converts all values to integers:

```
public class IntValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return String.valueOf((int) value);
    }
}
```

You can then use this formatter for both `BarData` and individual `BarDataSet` objects like this:

```
barData/barDataSet.setValueFormatter(new IntValueFormatter());
```

For more information on `IValueFormatter`, check the following links:

- [`IValueFormatter` Wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface) on Github
- [`IValueFormatter` Documentation](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.0-beta1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/ValueFormatter.html) on JitPack (v3.0.0-beta1)

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest option is the following

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.##");

 mChartData.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
              return decimalFormat.format(value);
            }
        });
```